# How can I display a button in the onCreate method of an activity based on a given condition?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-button

I want to display a button in an activity, but the text and background of the button are different if a specific condition is met by the user. How can I initialise the same button in the OnCreate method, having two different designs based on a condition?

Comment: **intialize by doing** Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
**for changing background and text based on condition** 
if (conditionMet){
    button.setText("Condition Met");}
else {
    button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.whatever)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here Maybe this help

```
 val btnGet = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnGet)

    if (id == 1){   //Your condition 

        btnGet.text = id.toString()
        btnGet.visibility = View.VISIBLE    //Make Sure in xml it is gone 
        btnGet.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"))
        btnGet.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
    }else{
        btnGet.text = id.toString()
         btnGet.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        btnGet.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBB86FC"))
        btnGet.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF03DAC5"))

    }
```

If you want the full code I will share it with you
Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

**1**. You can change this properties in run time.

**2**. You can create two drawables files to set in the button background, but the text you still needing to change in runtime.

**3**. And you can use data binding in your xml file, using layout Data, like:
[Google Link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions)